# EF Db-first, can EF populate non-entity properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model in DB-first with my own POCOs, where I have mapped lots of entities to the database. For one of these POCOs I have now added a new property, which is populated outside of normal usage of EF, via a stored procedure, with the result restructured to fit my needs.

Is it possible to get EF to populate it without doing it myself manually? If I do context.Datas.Include("NewData"), I would be able to somehow map what's needed for it to include NewData, e.i. a method call.

In my scenario I do only need to have read capabilities, I will not need to update any data via EF.

```
public class Data
{
    ...
    public NewData NewData {get;set;}
}
```

today filled with:

```
var dataObject = contect.Datas.First(...);
dataObject.NewData = context.GetDataFromStoredProcedure(...);
```

but would like to be able to:

```
var dataObject = contect.Datas.Include("NewData").Where(...);
```